# Progressive web app launched in standalone does not detect site updates

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've a Progressive web app that is added on my home screen. I've chosen standalone run type, I've a `service-worker` running in it.

All working perfectly, only one doubt: if I update my site (with its relative `service-worker`, I can see updates if I load it directly into browser, but if I launch it by home added link I see always the old site.

There is a way to request updates when launching my site in standalone mode?

Comment: What's the `start_url` that you're using in your Web App Manifest? If you navigate to the same `start_url` in Chrome on your device, do you see different content than what you see in your add-to-homescreen link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging I've discovered the simple solution, I report it for others.

iOS does not support `service-workers`, so that is not the problem.
iOS keep in cache many resources, so the solution is to add a parameter to the various imports like so:

The best solution to ensure updates is to add an hash of imported as the parameter.

Alternatively we can use a timestamp to ensure that resources are ALWAYS updated.

To attach this parameter we can import these resources injecting them with javascript, like so

```
/**
 * inietta uno script nella pagina
 */
function appendScript(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;   // async false to wait for previous file loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}

// create parameter with date
var currVersion = '?v=' + new Date().getTime();

// get head html element
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

// append script
appendScript('app.js' + currVersion);

// append css
head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css' + currVersion + '">');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking "is there a way to dynamically update my precached assets without updating my service worker?" 
Yes!
I have been working on an upgrade to the JSON cache strategy here -> https://serviceworke.rs/json-cache.html We will publish this soon!

Comment: it sounds interesting...i'll try and i'll advice you, thanks in advance

Comment: chris yout json cache strategy is supported by ios safari?

Comment: Yes it will. I have been doing this mechanism for about 6-7 years now. With service workers I have been upgrading it and migrating from localStorage to indexeddb.
This is a presentation I gave @ Velocity a few years ago on the overall concepts -> https://youtu.be/GKxkzu0pHUc?list=PLqf5nhDkyqZHR6fQxCYoqPIJwiRdoMXMf
This is an article on using localStorage for caching I wrote a long time ago -> https://love2dev.com/blog/use-local-storage-to-make-your-single-page-web-application-rock/

I hope to have new code for service worker completed this week with a legacy browser (iOS) fallback.